# How can I force my Widgets to use a dark theme?

Tags: android, themes, light

In my application, I used `Theme.Holo.Light` to make the ActionBar look light and I am pretty pleased with the result.

The only problem is that all my widgets (EditText, Spinner, etc..) are acting like the background was white, while I set it a dark blue:

[image]

Is there an easy way in the style.xml file where I can force everything to act like the theme was dark?

I know that I could theme the text color, background resources, etc.. But this would be a huge work.

Thank a lot for any hint that could help me to achieve that easily.

Edit: what sounds the best solution, but not working:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this (the easy way) you should use `Theme.Holo`. And Change the actionbar to `Theme.Holo.Light`.

extend theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.ActionBar"></style>
```

use `getActionBar().getThemedContext()` as the context for inflating your views.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer, but using Holo.Light in MyTheme.Dark will bring black text everywhere and that's what I want to avoid. I cannot use code everytime I inflate a view, that would be too much work, I really plan to use a style in xml if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Holoeverywhere library to achieve your result.

[HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/)

Comment: Lol, if you click on the "Christophe' link on the project, you will understand that it's me ;-) but HoloEverywhere use standart Holo items on Android > 3.0 so won't be usefull ;-) Problem will remain teh same!